How to serve html files in Spring Boot 3.1.5
All of our applications have a simple version.html file that our ops team manually injects into the root of the deployed application when it is built.  Accessing it when navigating to http://<appath>.com/version.html has worked fine for years in our older Node and Grails apps.  However, once we moved to Spring Boot 3.1.5 we can no longer access it  as we used to be able to.
I found resources like:

How to serve .html files with Spring
How to map requests to HTML file in Spring MVC?
How can I serve static html from spring boot?
how to serve static content in springboot 2.2.6?

However, these all seem to indicate that I need to nest the html file within another folder for it to be picked up and hosted successfully.
After talking with the ops team, they aren't going to be able to move the file to a new location.
So, is there any way to host the version.html right off of the root path of the app?

Can you provide more details about exactly how your application is deployed and how the HTML file is injected when it's built?

We have an ops team who manages this.  We have a Jenkins process that picks up new commits to master in github, builds a war file, spins up a docker container, deploys the war file to it, starts up the server.
At some point after the war file is deployed, but before application start, the ops team says they use a utility that manages insertion of the html file which calls a function called "insert_file_at_root".
Not sure if there is another function that can be called so we can throw the html file into src/main/resources/static/ or another location.  Or, is there a way to configure spring?

If it's a war file, a file at its root should already be accessible as that's how war files work. Without knowing exactly what insert_file_at_root is doing and how the war file looks on disk, I can't say why that is apparently not working.
